# How to create duplicate for lines of code

Tags: python, loops

I would like to create duplicate of lines of code, for eg.

At present my code looks like:
mdb.Model(name='**model-3**', modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
a = mdb.models['**model-3**'].rootAssembly

My code should look like:
mdb.Model(name='**model-3**', modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
a = mdb.models['**model-3**'].rootAssembly

mdb.Model(name='**model-4**', modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
a = mdb.models['**model-4**'].rootAssembly

mdb.Model(name='**model-5**', modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
a = mdb.models['**model-5**'].rootAssembly

where the difference is only in underlined. Is there a simple way to create this loop?

Comment: Why not just use a `for-loop` and format strings to generate `model-X`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can i use this for loop to create the lines within the code not as in print() on output?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking. Can you update the question with an example of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the strings in a for loop using string formatting.

```
for i in range(3,6):
    mdb.Model(name='model-{}'.format(i), modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
    a = mdb.models['model-{}'.format(i)].rootAssembly
```

If you are using Python-3 you can alternatively use `f-strings`.

```
for i in range(3,6):
    mdb.Model(name=f'model-{i}', modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
    a = mdb.models[f'model-{i}'].rootAssembly
```

This code is functionally equivalent to your example.